# Classic asp Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2000, ado

I use insert command to linked server such as

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
INSERT linked_server.dbname.dbo.table SELECT a,b,c, FROM my_table
```

This query It seems fine from smss, but when I run it through classic asp adodb.connection it return this

```
Description: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.
Help context: 0
Help file: 
Native error: 7405
Error number: -2147217900
Error source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
SQL state: 37000
```

How can I get the same result as in smss? Thanks

Comment: I just realized that my company framework use sp_executeTransaction to call queries. And in that sp Ansi nulls set to be off.